# Error : Could not find the correct Provider above this Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem using Flutter Provider. My flow is like this : After addPeople page, direct to home_page.dart and then the user will fill any information that required in the add_player_page.dart. -> from there it preforms save to db

This is addPeople.dart page code :

```
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPage createState() => _InputPage();
}

class _InputPage extends State<InputPage> {
  final allPlayerProvider = Provider.of<Players>;
  List<Widget> _textFields = [];
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  void _addTextField() {
    if (_textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _textFields.add(TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_outlined),
            iconColor: MyColor.color2,
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _textFields.removeLast();
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [
                MyColor.color1,
                MyColor.color2,
              ]),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Add People',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            actions: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePageAdd()));
                  },
                  icon: Text(
                    'Save',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                topRight: Radius.circular(50),
              ),
            ),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'With you and',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: MyColor.color2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: _textEditingController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.person_outlined),
                            iconColor: MyColor.color2,
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _textFields.removeLast();
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ..._textFields,
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: _addTextField,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 120,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: MyColor.color2,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Add More +',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

This is add_player_page.dart code :

```
class AddPlayer extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = "/add-player";
  final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController quantityController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController();

  AddPlayer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final players = Provider.of<Players>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ADD PLAYER"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: () {
              players
                  .addPlayer(
                nameController.text,
                quantityController.text,
                priceController.text,
              )
                  .then(
                (response) {
                  print("Kembali ke Home & kasih notif snack bar");
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(
                      content: Text("Berhasil ditambahkan"),
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                    ),
                  );
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                autocorrect: false,
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Nama"),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                controller: nameController,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Quantity"),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                controller: quantityController,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Price"),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                controller: priceController,
                onEditingComplete: () {
                  players
                      .addPlayer(
                    nameController.text,
                    quantityController.text,
                    priceController.text,
                  )
                      .then(
                    (response) {
                      print("Kembali ke Home & kasih notif snack bar");
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text("Berhasil ditambahkan"),
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                        ),
                      );
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    players
                        .addPlayer(
                      nameController.text,
                      quantityController.text,
                      priceController.text,
                    )
                        .then(
                      (response) {
                        print("Kembali ke Home & kasih notif snack bar");
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                            content: Text("Berhasil ditambahkan"),
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                          ),
                        );
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Submit",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is home_page.dart code :

```
class HomePageAdd extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageAdd({super.key});

  @override
  _HomePageAddState createState() => _HomePageAddState();
}

class _HomePageAddState extends State<HomePageAdd> {
  bool isInit = true;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (isInit) {
      Provider.of<Players>(context).initialData();
    }
    isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final allPlayerProvider = Provider.of<Players>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ALL PLAYERS"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, AddPlayer.routeName);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: (allPlayerProvider.jumlahPlayer == 0)
          ? Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "No Data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, AddPlayer.routeName);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Add Player",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: allPlayerProvider.jumlahPlayer,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var id = allPlayerProvider.allPlayer[index].id;
                return ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                      context,
                      AddPlayer.routeName,
                      arguments: id,
                    );
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    allPlayerProvider.allPlayer[index].name,
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    allPlayerProvider.allPlayer[index].price,
                  ),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      allPlayerProvider.deletePlayer(id).then(
                        (_) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(
                              content: Text("Berhasil dihapus"),
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is players.dart inside provider folder

```
class Players with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Player> _allPlayer = [];

  List<Player> get allPlayer => _allPlayer;

  int get jumlahPlayer => _allPlayer.length;

  Player selectById(String id) =>
      _allPlayer.firstWhere((element) => element.id == id);

  Future<void> addPlayer(String name, String quantity, String price) {

    Uri url = Uri.parse(
        "https://splitbill-8736a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/players.json");
    return http
        .post(
      url,
      body: json.encode(
        {
          "name": name,
          "quantity": quantity,
          "price": price,
        },
      ),
    )
        .then(
      (response) {
        print("THEN FUNCTION");
        _allPlayer.add(
          Player(
            id: json.decode(response.body)["name"].toString(),
            name: name,
            quantity: quantity,
            price: price,
          ),
        );

        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> editPlayer(
      String id, String name, String quantity, String price) {
    Uri url = Uri.parse(
        "https://splitbill-8736a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/players/$id.json");
    return http
        .put(
      url,
      body: json.encode(
        {
          "name": name,
          "position": quantity,
          "price": price,
        },
      ),
    )
        .then(
      (response) {
        Player selectPlayer =
            _allPlayer.firstWhere((element) => element.id == id);
        selectPlayer.name = name;
        selectPlayer.quantity = quantity;
        selectPlayer.price = price;
        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> deletePlayer(String id) {
    Uri url = Uri.parse(
        "https://splitbill-8736a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/players/$id.json");
    return http.delete(url).then(
      (response) {
        _allPlayer.removeWhere((element) => element.id == id);
        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> initialData() async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse(
        "https://http-req-bec2d-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/players.json");

    var hasilGetData = await http.get(url);

    var dataResponse = json.decode(hasilGetData.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

    dataResponse.forEach(
      (key, value) {
        _allPlayer.add(
          Player(
            id: key,
            quantity: value["quantity"],
            name: value["name"],
            price: value["price"],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    print("BERHASIL MASUKAN DATA LIST");

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is player.dart inside model folder:

```
class Player {
  String id, name, quantity, price;

  Player({required this.price, required this.id, required this.quantity, required this.name});
}
```

My folder structure is like this :

I expected after addPeople page then direct to home_page.dart and then the user can fill information like item name, price, and quantity then saved to my firebase

after addPeople on my emulator (vscode), this happen :

Comment: You have to add that provider in the root of the widget tree for it to be seen everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you providing `Players` from?

You should provide Players from the MaterialApp so it can be accessible to all the various widgets in your app i.e. `addPlayer.dart`, `addPeople.dart`.

Otherwise, if you provide Players from a widget below the MaterialApp, you will have to explicitly provide it when you navigate to other widgets by using the `ChangeNotifierProvider.value()` constructor.